# Javascript alert error on a load-balanced environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, f5

We have 3 servers in a DMZ that serve our student web portal. We've been seeing this error:

```
The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

after clicking next page on a grid pager. On inspecting element, this is the code that gets executed: `__doPostBack('pg0$V$1','')"`. Now, this works as it should if I go into the individual servers and click next page on this table but throws the error above when behind the f5 load-balancer. We have no clue why this is happening. One speculation is since we do inline http to https, that could be a potential issue. We have no control over the ASP.NET code since it's provided by a third-party but the ASP.NET code doesn't seem to be the issue here since it works on the individual servers.

Comment: What type of persistence are you using on the F5 Loadbalancers? Are you sure requests are going to the same server?  Which version of F5 are you running and do you have any profiles applied to the Virtual Server (VIP) configuration?

Comment: We use sticky sessions using an AES encrypted cookie containing the IP of the server selected. Yes requests are going to same server as per Wireshark. We use BigIP stream profile feature to rewrite http to https and vice-versa.